# pandas dict of dataframe values, need graphing suggestion

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have a cluster of nodes where each one produces about 200 statistics on the the performance of CPU/network/disk etc. I have so far looped though various node's log files and  parsed them into a data frame object per node and put into a dict keyed by node id:

(Here the first column is the index label of the DataFrame)

```
    { 'node00': 
            <DaFrame-display-begin>
                               core 0    core 1    core 2   core 3   group 0
    Avg IPC (w/ idle)           0.09      0.12     0.06      0.06      0.08
    Avg CPI (w/ idle)          11.17      8.03    15.62     16.97     12.95
    Avg IPC (w/o idle)          0.48      0.78     0.64      0.63      0.63
    Avg CPI (w/o idle)          2.10      1.28     1.56      1.59      1.63
    User IPC (w/o idle)         0.70      1.02     0.85      0.84      0.85
    ........................................
    ,
     'node01':
            <DataFrame-display-begin>
    Avg IPC (w/ idle)           0.05      0.12     0.06      0.06      0.08
    Avg CPI (w/ idle)           9.17      8.03    15.62     16.97     12.95
    Avg IPC (w/o idle)          0.48      0.78     0.64      0.63      0.63
    Avg CPI (w/o idle)          2.10      1.28     1.56      1.59      1.63
    User IPC (w/o idle)         0.70      1.02     0.85      0.84      0.85

    }
```

I plan to write a general purpose function that would take the name of the statistic as the argument and then plot bar graphs of the particular statistic across all nodes in the cluster. Bars of different cores can be stacked or side-by-side. But the x-axis will points need to be the nodes for easy comparison.

Any suggestions? I am new to Pandas/matplotlib so any hint would be great.

Comment: From various examples, I could manage to create the bar plots. Changed the stats name to a column instead of being an index, which later allows to choose only those rows where the statitis matches the argument. Also added the node value as a column. Appended all the nodes' DataFrames into a bigger list. Finally doing pivot table and putting the pivots into a dataframe and plotting the dataframe in bar mode created the necessary graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is to merge all dataframes together, then you could use all nice Panda functions to slice and mix-and-match anyway you want.

Lets first create some sample data:

```
# node1
index = ['Avg IPC (w/ idle)', 'Avg CPI (w/ idle)', 'Avg IPC (w/o idle)', 'Avg CPI (w/o idle)', 'User IPC (w/o idle)']

core0 = [0.09, 11.17, 0.48, 2.10, 0.70]
core1 = [0.12, 8.03, 0.78, 1.28, 1.02]
core2 = [0.06, 15.62, 0.64, 1.56, 0.85]
core3 = [0.06, 16.97, 0.63, 1.59, 0.84]
group = [0.08, 12.95, 0.63, 1.63, 0.85]

data = {'core0': core0, 'core1': core1, 'core2': core2, 'core3': core3, 'group': group}
node01 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

# node2
index = ['Avg IPC (w/ idle)', 'Avg CPI (w/ idle)', 'Avg IPC (w/o idle)', 'Avg CPI (w/o idle)', 'User IPC (w/o idle)']

core0 = [0.33, 11.17, 0.48, 2.10, 0.70]
core1 = [0.12, 8.99, 0.78, 1.28, 1.02]
core2 = [0.06, 15.62, 0.64, 1.56, 9.99]
core3 = [0.06, 16.99, 9.99, 1.59, 0.84]
group = [0.08, 12.95, 0.63, 9.99, 0.85]

data = {'core0': core0, 'core1': core1, 'core2': core2, 'core3': core3, 'group': group}

node02 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

alldfs = {'node01': node01, 'node02': node02}
```

The alldfs should be similar to your dict. I would merge them like this:

```
# create 1 DataFrame
dfall = pd.concat(alldfs)

# name the levels for easy access
dfall.index.names = ['node','stat']
dfall.columns.name = 'core'

# pivot the 'stat' layer to the columns so only the nodes are on the index
dfall = dfall.unstack('stat')
```

This gives you a nice single DataFrame containing all data, a basic plotting function using Pandas build-in functionality can be as simple as:

```
def plotstat(df, stat):
    return df.xs(stat, axis=1, level=1).plot(kind='bar', title=stat)

plotstat(dfall, 'Avg IPC (w/ idle)')
```

Which gives:

[image]

---

You could of course use stack/unstack to structure your DataFrame a bit different depending on the amount of data and the way you will be using it most.